# next() called in OnActionExecutionAsync does not call parent's OnActionExecutionAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this controller in my .NET Core web app:

> public abstract class BaseController : Controller

This controller has this code:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // more code
    }

    await next();
}
```

On the other hand, I have other controller, this way:

> public class DefaultPageBaseController : BaseController

That controller, also overrides OnActionExecutionAsync this way:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        
    }

    if (context.Result == null)
        await next();
}
```

Finally, I have a controller such as:

> public class HomeController : DefaultPageBaseController

When debugging, I see that the `OnActionExecutionAsync` from `DefaultPageBaseController` is called only. Not the one belonging to `BaseController` even when the `next()` method is being called.

What may be wrong?

Comment: You override and provide a new implementation of `OnActionExecutionAsync` method in DefaultPageBaseController class, so this new implementation is used, which is default behavior. If you'd like to execute BaseController `OnActionExecutionAsync` method, you can call `await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);` within the overridden method in the DefaultPageBaseController class.